# Joomla map issue (image not displaying)

Tags: joomla1.5

I am using Joomla 1.5 for one of my CMS project. In this I am using JCE editor. Once I get the embed code from google map, I just paste that code in one article and save that article. It gives the only hyperlink to map but it doesn't show the image. What's the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JCE is a terrific editor. But it likes to clean stuff up, your code for the map is probably stripped out. You can check it by clicking on "Show/Hide" link in the top left corner just above the editor. Try working in the "Hide" mode and enter HTML and then save and check.